# Regular Erdos Renyi Graph

Tags: probability, random-graphs

For $G(n,1/2)$, the Erdos-Renyi graph on $n$ vertices where each edge appears with probability $1/2$.  What is the probability (asymptotics as n tends to infinity) that the resulting graph is $n/2$-regular (assuming $n/2$ is an integer)?  I am just looking for some rough bounds.  In general, what is the probability that $G(n,p)$ is $d$ regular?

Comment: Incredibly small

Answer (score 1):

This question requires counting $d$ regular graphs, which apparently is known asymptotically for various $d$.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there

When you know the count, you can just multiply by $p^{nd/2} (1-p)^{n^2 - nd/2}$, which gives you the probability that you want.

(Judging by that MO post, I would guess that the probability you are looking for is not a simple one)

Comment: I see, thanks.  I've altered the question to just get the rough order of magnitude.